# How to get Description of Enum to add into NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have enum as,

```
public enum ClearAttributes
{
    S_DURATION,
    S_TYPE

}
```

I am adding items to NameValueCollection by using description from enum

```
NameValueCollection nvCollection = new NameValueCollection();
nvCollection.Add(ClearAttributes.S_DURATION.ToString(), "SomeText1");
nvCollection.Add(ClearAttributes.S_TYPE.ToString(), "SomeText2");
```

And I want description(Key) and value both, but in description it is always giving index value as 0, 1. By using following code.

```
nvCollection.Keys[i];//For Description
nvCollection[i];//For Value
```

So please help me to get the Description from enum.

Comment: Why not use a Dictionary<> instead of a NameValueCollection ?

Comment: Already one function is there, which is expecting NVC, and it will return me the xml format so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this :

```
var description = nvCollection.GetKey(i);
var value =  nvCollection.Get(i);
```

An alternativa maybe can be this :

```
IDictionary<ClearAttributes,string> collection = new Dictionary<ClearAttributes, string>();
collection.Add(ClearAttributes.S_DURATION, "SomeText1");
collection.Add(ClearAttributes.S_TYPE, "SomeText2");

string value = string.Empty;
collection.TryGetValue(ClearAttributes.S_DURATION, out value);
```

Comment: Actually the problem is not here, while adding to NameValueCollection only it is going as integers(index)